# What's the best way to set a StringBuilder object?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I created a StringBuilder object without any value and appended some values afterwards. I later wanted to replace the object with an entirely different string.

Here's the code:

```
StringBuilder finalVersion = new StringBuilder();
finalVersion.append("6.0")
for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
    if(/*...*/){
       finalVersion.append(".2");
    } else {
       finalVersion.append(".1");
    }
    if (/*...*/) {
        if (/*...*/) {
            finalVersion = new StringBuilder("Invalid parameter"));
         }
    }
}
```

What I've done is I created a new object to change the value, but perhaps there is a better approach without using `stringBuilder.setLength(0);`.

Could someone help?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with creating a new instance.

Comment: yeah, I agree, but it sounds strange for some quality tools, I mean, is really necessery create another object to set it?

Comment: If creating a new instance is unacceptable to you, setlength is your only other option.

Comment: take a look at the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To solve it I created a new object to change the value but I guess there is a better approach without use `sb.setLength(0)`

Both of those are good approaches.  Another is `sb.delete(0, sb.length())`.

And when you want to replace the existing string content, `sb.replace(0, sb.length(), "new content")` is another option.

It really depends what your goal is:

- Calling `new StringBuffer(...)` will give you a freshly allocated object with either the default capacity or a capacity that you specify.
- The `setLength`, `delete` and `replace` approaches will recycle the existing object.  This has advantages and disadvantages.

  - On the plus side, you don't allocate a new object<sup>1</sup> ... so less garbage.
  - On the minus side, the string buffer uses the same amount of space as before, whether or not it *needs* to.  Also, if you do this repeatedly, the chances are that the buffer and its backing array will be tenured by the GC, adding to the long-term memory load.  You can free the unused capacity by calling `sb.trimToSize()`, but that is liable to cause a reallocation; i.e. what you were trying to avoid by not using `new`.

My advice would be to use `new` *unless* either the context means that you
can't, or your profiling tells you that `new` is generating too much garbage.

Looking at the code<sup>2</sup>, I think that `setLength` should be marginally faster than `delete` for emptying a `StringBuffer`.  It gets more complicated when you are replacing the contents with new contents.  Now you are comparing

```
   sb.setLength(); sb.append("new content");
```

versus

```
   sb.replace(0, sb.length(), "new content");
```

It needs to be measured ... if you care enough<sup>3</sup> about performance to be comparing the cases.

---

<sup>1 - Unless the replacement string is large enough that the buffer needs to grow to hold it.</sup>

<sup>2 - By my reading of various versions of the `StringBuilder` and `AbstractStringBuilder` code, the `delete` method will always call `System.arraycopy`.  However, to understand the performance impact, one would need to benchmark this carefully for different sizes of `StringBuilder` and across different Java versions.</sup>

<sup>3 - Actually, if you *need to* care.  Beware the evils of premature optimization.</sup>

Comment: What a nice description! It will help me in the future. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#replace-int-int-java.lang.String-). This method doesn't create a new `StringBuilder` object.

```
builder.replace(0, b.length(), "Invalid parameter");
```

Or, if doing it in two statements is fine with you, you can `setLength(0)`, then `append`.

But really, you shouldn't worry about creating a new `StringBuilder` unless you actually encounter performance problems.